# Rename VM in vCenter

Tags: virtual-machine, vsphere

I have this VM that had the name 'X' initially. I renamed it to 'Y'. So when I browse for this VM in the datastore after renaming, will the folder for the VM be name with X or Y?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Renaming the VM will **not** change the file names in the datastore.

You can find more information here: [VMWare KB](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1029513)